# Can I validate the content of a string in my JSON schema in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to specify that a string can only be one of four values.  How can I do that using the [jsonschema](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) library?

Sample code:

```
"value_params": {
    "required": ["positions", "userId"],
    "properties": {
        "userId": {"type": "integer"},
        "positions": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": ["partnerUserId", "userType"],
                "properties": {
                    "partnerUserId": {"type": "integer"},
                    "userType": {"type": "string"}
                },
                "additionalProperties": False
            }
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": False
},
```

The above works fine.  What would I need to add to require `userType` be one of only 4 values?

Comment: Please offer your code, and the tutorial has showed completed usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [example schema](http://json-schema.org/example2.html).

Use `enum` to restrict a value to a fixed set of values:

```
"label": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
}
```

It is also possible to define a regex pattern:

```
"label": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^value1|value2|value3|value4$"
}
```